# force close when I try to type in number or alphabet even though I have set a isnumeric method

Tags: android

I wanted to do a isnumeric method,
to check that IF user enter blank/ alphabet, it will toast "please enter a number"

I have to no idea, why when I type the first edit text box in alphabet format , 
it will have no error, 
however, when I type the second edit text box in alphabet format or number format, 
a force close error will be shown.

I've put the method for all my edit text , but it doesn't seems to work.

```
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "4dg"
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at com.example.fuellogproject.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:197)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7562)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9383)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:676)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:196)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-26 15:23:43.078: E/AndroidRuntime(30816):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)





  public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.cancelBTN){

            Intent viewAll=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewAll.class);
            startActivity(viewAll);


        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.saveBTN){
            // Get the values provided by the user via the UI
             String date = dateEdit.getText().toString();
             String price = priceEdit.getText().toString();
             String pump = pumpEdit.getText().toString();
             String tcost = costView.getText().toString();
             String odometer = odometerEdit.getText().toString();
             String fcon = fconView.getText().toString();

             if(isNumeric(priceEdit.getText().toString())){
                 Intent viewAll=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewAll.class);
                 startActivity(viewAll);
       if(!odometer.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
             {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                 editor.putString("ODO", odometer.trim());
                 editor.commit();
             }
             else
             {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                 editor.putString("ODO", "NA");
                 editor.commit();
             }
            // Pass above values to the setter methods in POJO class
             fuelLogPojo fuelLogPojoObj = new fuelLogPojo();
             fuelLogPojoObj.setdate(date);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setprice(price);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setpump(pump);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setcost(tcost);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setodometer(odometer);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setfcon(fcon);
            // Add an undergraduate with his all details to a ArrayList
             fuelLogArrayList.add(fuelLogPojoObj);

            // Inserting undergraduate details to the database is doing in a separate method

            insertLog(fuelLogPojoObj);

             }
             else if (priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) 
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


             else  if(isNumeric(pumpEdit.getText().toString())){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             else if (pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             else  if(isNumeric(odometerEdit.getText().toString())){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             else if (odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
    else
             {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
```

full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // TableLayout tablelayout_Log = null;
   private Button saveButton = null;
   private Button cancelButton = null;
   // Button searchButton = null;
   private   static EditText dateEdit; 
   private   EditText priceEdit;
   private    EditText pumpEdit;
   private    TextView costView;
   private    EditText odometerEdit;
   private    TextView fconView;
   private     TextWatcher textWatcher;
   private    String priceEditStr ="",pumpEditStr="";
   private    String  odmEditStr = "";
   private     String lastOdm = "";
     private ArrayList<fuelLogPojo> fuelLogArrayList;

double result;
double resultCon;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
SharedPreferences sp;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;




    public boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        costView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tcost);
        dateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        priceEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelprice);
        pumpEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelpump);
        odometerEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.odometer);
        fconView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fcon);
        fuelLogArrayList = new ArrayList<fuelLogPojo>();

        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBTN);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBTN);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);


         //Shared preference 

        sp=this.getSharedPreferences("result_store", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        lastOdm=sp.getString("ODO", lastOdm);

        if(lastOdm.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NA"))
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+lastOdm.trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+lastOdm.trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




       // DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
       // lastOdm = dbAdaptor.getLastOdometer();
//Check that your database is enable to fetch the value or not? 
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+lastOdm,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        dateEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });


           priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                  if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                       priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                       pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                   if(isNumeric(priceEdit.getText().toString())){
                  if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                  {
                    result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                    costView.setText(" "+result);
                  }
                   }
                   else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

               }
           });

           pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                       priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                  if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                       pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                  if(isNumeric(pumpEdit.getText().toString())){
                  if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                     {
                       result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                       costView.setText(" "+result);
                     }
                  }
                  else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
               }
           });







           odometerEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }



               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it

                   if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                       odmEditStr = odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                   if(isNumeric(odometerEdit.getText().toString())){
                  if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !lastOdm.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !lastOdm.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NA"))
                     {

                      resultCon = (Double.parseDouble(odmEditStr) - Double.parseDouble(lastOdm) )/ Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                       fconView.setText(" "+resultCon);
                     }
                   }
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

               }
           });

    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.cancelBTN){

            Intent viewAll=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewAll.class);
            startActivity(viewAll);


        }else if(view.getId() == R.id.saveBTN){
            // Get the values provided by the user via the UI
             String date = dateEdit.getText().toString();
             String price = priceEdit.getText().toString();
             String pump = pumpEdit.getText().toString();
             String tcost = costView.getText().toString();
             String odometer = odometerEdit.getText().toString();
             String fcon = fconView.getText().toString();

             if(isNumeric(priceEdit.getText().toString())){
                 Intent viewAll=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewAll.class);
                 startActivity(viewAll);
       if(!odometer.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
             {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                 editor.putString("ODO", odometer.trim());
                 editor.commit();
             }
             else
             {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                 editor.putString("ODO", "NA");
                 editor.commit();
             }
            // Pass above values to the setter methods in POJO class
             fuelLogPojo fuelLogPojoObj = new fuelLogPojo();
             fuelLogPojoObj.setdate(date);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setprice(price);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setpump(pump);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setcost(tcost);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setodometer(odometer);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setfcon(fcon);
            // Add an undergraduate with his all details to a ArrayList
             fuelLogArrayList.add(fuelLogPojoObj);

            // Inserting undergraduate details to the database is doing in a separate method

            insertLog(fuelLogPojoObj);

             }
             else if (priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) 
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


             else  if(isNumeric(pumpEdit.getText().toString())){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             else if (pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             else  if(isNumeric(odometerEdit.getText().toString())){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             else if (odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
    else
             {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

            // Release from the existing UI and go back to the previous UI
             //Intent viewAll=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewAll.class);
           //  startActivity(viewAll);

        }
    }


    private void insertLog(fuelLogPojo fuelLogPojoObj) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // First we have to open our DbHelper class by creating a new object of that
        AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

        // Then we need to get a writable SQLite database, because we are going to insert some values
        // SQLiteDatabase has methods to create, delete, execute SQL commands, and perform other common database management tasks.
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();

        // ContentValues class is used to store a set of values that the ContentResolver can process.
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        // Get values from the POJO class and passing them to the ContentValues class
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE, fuelLogPojoObj.getdate());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PRICE, fuelLogPojoObj.getprice());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_FUEL, fuelLogPojoObj.getpump());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_COST, fuelLogPojoObj.getcost());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ODM, fuelLogPojoObj.getodometer());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_CON, fuelLogPojoObj.getfcon());


        // Now we can insert the data in to relevant table
        // I am going pass the id value, which is going to change because of our insert method, to a long variable to show in Toast
        long affectedColumnId = sqliteDatabase.insert(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, null, contentValues);

        // It is a good practice to close the database connections after you have done with it
        sqliteDatabase.close();

        // I am not going to do the retrieve part in this post. So this is just a notification for satisfaction ;-)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Values inserted column ID is :" + affectedColumnId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        





    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public EditText editText;
        DatePicker dpResult;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        dateEdit.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        // set selected date into datepicker also
}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You String `priceEditStr` contains 2 letters that is 'dg', therefore it is crashing while trying to convert to double. You should handle expected `Exceptions` while converting values. 
Please edit your code like this:

```
           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
              //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
              if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                   priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
               if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                   pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

              if((!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))&&((priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().matches("[0-9]+"))&&(pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().matches("[0-9]+"))))
              {
                result = "";
                try
                {
                    result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr.replace("dg", "").trim());   
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
                {
                    //Stack trace will be printed in your Logcat, if the app crashes in the try block with NumberFormatException exception      
                    nfe.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //Stack trace will be printed in your Logcat, if the app crashes in the try block with some unhandled exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                costView.setText(" "+result);
              }
              else 
              {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
```

Also Edit you `isNumeric(..)` method like this:

```
public boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
    return str.matches("[0-9]+"); 
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ive just edited my code as shown above, when I type alphabet, it will toast message.
However, when I want to delete the alphabet and input a number, there will be a force close error

Comment: You are not checking if the `EditText's` values are only Numbers or not, i have edited the `If(..)` condition in the `AfterTextChanged(...)` delegate. Now it will check if the Strings are Numeric or not before converting them or else will show a Toast.

Comment: Your `isNumeric(...)` Method was the real problem here. Please edit that as described in the answer and the code should work fine.